# Custom 404 page using Angular and Express

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am using a MEAN stack and I am trying to build a custom 404 page for my project using Angular.

In Angular **app.module.ts** I have written this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'students',
        component: StudentComponent,
        data: {title: 'Student List'}
    },
    {
        path: 'student-details/:id',
        component: StudentDetailComponent,
        data: {title: 'Student Details'}
    },
    {
        path: 'student-create',
        component: StudentCreateComponent,
        data: {title: 'Create a new Student'}
    },
    {
        path: 'student-edit/:id',
        component: StudentEditComponent,
        data: {title: 'Edit Student'}
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/students',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent,
        data: {title: 'Page Not Found'}
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        StudentComponent,
        StudentDetailComponent,
        StudentCreateComponent,
        StudentEditComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes,
            {enableTracing: true}
        )
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

But in fact I think that when I write an URL that doesn't exist Express make a response, not Angular. I know that Express is answering because, when I removed this code from **server.js**:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   var err = new Error('Not Found');
   err.status = 404;
   next(err);
});
```

When I write an url that doesn't exist, I get the answer "**Cannot GET /urlThatDoesntExist**".
The matter is that the other routing urls set in Angular are working but the 404 page is not.

I am using Express to serve the Angular app using:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

How can I set the Angular 404 page working above Express? Thanks!

Comment: You are using express to serve the angular app?

Comment: Yes, I made an edit writing the line of code that I have

Comment: You need redirect to index.html when express detect the 404 error, with this way angular get the control of this route

Comment: I didn't figure out how to make the redirect but I think that it's obviously possible. The solution of paul make it works. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every request to reach angular (so you can handle 404s on the client side) you can use an express route like this:

```
//  all routes lead to to index.html
const router = express.Router();
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(DIR, 'index.html'));
});
this.express.use('*', router);
```

Comment: I have just added the prefix /dist/ to index.html and it works! Thanks!